# Multiple NavigationLink with ForEach

Tags: json, swift, xcode, swiftui

I have a json file that contains an array of school classes name className, when I try to show the classes using Text(className[I]), I get this error:

> Ambiguous subscript with base type '[String]' and index type '_'

(the i as in for loop).

Here is the code I am using

```
@EnvironmentObject private var userData: UserData
    var classes: Classes
    ForEach(self.userData.classes) { classes in
            Section(header: Text(classes.schoolForm)) {
                    ForEach(self.classes.className.sorted(), id: \.self) { classNameId in
                            NavigationLink(destination: Text("Testing...")) {
                                        Text(!self.classes.className[classNameId]) //The error shows here 
                                    }            
                            }
                     }
             }
```

Answer (score 0):

The Answer is:

```
@EnvironmentObject private var userData: UserData
    var classes: Classes
    ForEach(self.userData.classes) { classes in
            Section(header: Text(classes.schoolForm)) {
                    ForEach(self.classes.className.sorted(), id: \.self) { classNameId in
                            NavigationLink(destination: Text("Testing...")) {
                                        Text(classNameId)
                                    }            
                            }
                     }
             }
```

the classNameId is the data saved in the array of the classes